# How can I split a string into substrings?

Tags: java, android, string

I want to split the string `"KD-435"` into two substrings to check whether the first substring `"KD-"` begins with the following characters `"KD-"` and the second substring is number beteewn `"400-500"`.

I have the following method and I want to change it to do that at this position `if (ssid.startsWith("KD-"))`

```
private void check_wifi_available() {
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) this
            .getSystemService(this.WIFI_SERVICE);

    final List<ScanResult> results = wifiManager.getScanResults();
    if (results != null) {

        List<ScanResult> updatedResults = new ArrayList<ScanResult>();
        // pick wifi access ponits which begins with these "KD" characters.
        for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
            String ssid = results.get(i).SSID;
            if (ssid.startsWith("KD")) {

                updatedResults.add(results.get(i));
            }
        }
        if (updatedResults.size() > 0) {
            String a = calculateBestAccessPoint(updatedResults);
            textWifi.setText(a.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean substring?

Comment: yes I meant substring ^^ typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    String [] parts = ssid.split("-");

if(parts.length == 2)
{

    String firstPart = parts[0]; //That's KD
    String secondPart = parts[1]; //That's 435

    if(firstPart.equals("KD")&&Integer.parseInt(secondPart)>=400&&Integer.parseInt(secondPart)<=500)
    {
    //do whatever you want
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a regex to do it all in one fell swoop:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^KD-(4[0-9]{2}|500)$");
Matcher m = p.matcher("KD-411"); // Replace with your string.
if (m.matches()) {
    // It worked!
} else {
    // It didn't.
}
```

Comment: can you please explain me this regex ""^KD-(4[0-9]{2}|500)$""? does it contain all number between 400-500? what does the  number 4 mean here "4[0-9]"?

Comment: `4[0-9]{2}` means "4 followed by two digits in the range 0-9", i.e. this matches numbers 400-499. `4[0-9]{2}|500` matches numbers 400-499 or 500, i.e. 400-500. `^KD-` means "starts with KD-", and `$` means nothing follows the number in the range 400-500.

Comment: Exactly that! I think regexes are kind of fun -- it's sort of like a puzzle to come up with a pattern that will match exactly the strings that you want. They can come in handy quite often. If you're interested in learning how to read and write them, [this is a pretty good resource](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html).

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need to explicitly split it (in the sense of invoking `String.split`), e.g.

```
if (s.startsWith("KD-")) {
  int v = Integer.parseString(s.substring(3));
  if (v >= 400 && v <= 500) {
    // Do whatever.
  }
}
```

You would need to handle the fact that `s.substring(3)` might not be parseable as an integer.